# Orchard 1.8.1 Containable/Container Layouts

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I am using Orchard 1.8.1 and one of the sections of the site I'm building is for a standard photo gallery. Since all the modules involving photo galleries are ancient, I opted to stay native and try using custom content types to build it instead. The way I accomplished this is with a Photo Gallery content type that has the Container part associated, then a Photo Gallery Item content type that has the Containable part associated to it.

Using the Shape Tracing tool, I was able to build out the main gallery page that shows all the individual galleries, but when you go inside a single gallery is where I get lost. The attached screenshot probably shows it best, but in the `Content` zone, I can see there are two individual items contained under `Model.ContentItem.ContainerPart.ItemCount`, however I can't figure out how to access those individual items to build a template to show them. The point of the gallery page will be implementing the gallery from [Galleria](http://galleria.io/themes/twelve/), so whenever I view the individual page for the Photo Gallery content type, I need to access all child items underneath it to build this.

Any ideas?[image]

Comment: Why are you using container/containable for that, and not simply a media library picker field?

Comment: I needed to support images with titles/captions and it didn't seem like the media picker field lets you add things like that per image. Unless I missed something?

Comment: You can set the title and caption on each Image content item.

Comment: Well how about that - I had no idea. I never came across any documentation that said you could do this, hence going the significantly more difficult route. Thanks! Do you want to post this as an answer so you get the points or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a media library picker field configured for multiple media, and then edit each image to set its caption and title. Then, it's just a matter of customizing a template override in your theme to make it look exactly the way you want.